# Can't convert numpy array values to float32

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to convert a numpy array of `float64` to `float32`. The array is the concatenated version of two other arrays: `hist` and `n_zero_rows`:

```py
def someFunction(hist, imgs):
    samples = []
    for img in imgs:
        n_zero = img != 0
        n_zero_cols = n_zero.sum(0) / norm(n_zero.sum(0) + eps)
        n_zero_rows = n_zero.sum(1) / norm(n_zero.sum(1) + eps)

        features = np.concatenate((hist, n_zero_rows), axis=0)      
        samples.append(features)

    return np.float32(samples)
```

If I append the `samples` array with `hist` only, it works. But when I try to add the `n_zero_rows`, it raises an exception: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`. I checked the types of both the arrays and both of them are `numpy.ndarrays` and both elements in those arrays are `float64`.

EDIT: Oops! It can't really be tested. Here's more detail then: I made sure that my `n_zero_rows` array had the same amount dimensions as `hist`. Essentially, it is just checking the amount of non-zero pixels along every rows. You can try it yourself with any image. Here's the shape and type of both arrays:

```
Shape of img: (128, 128)
Shape of n_zero_rows: (128,)
Shape of hist: (120,)
type of n_zero_rows: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
type of hist: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And just to make sure, here's `n_zero_rows` for the first `img` in the loop (NORMALIZED):

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.03518132  0.04073627
  0.02777473  0.03703297  0.02777473  0.05925276  0.07406595  0.09258243
  0.11850551  0.14998354  0.15739014  0.15553849  0.15924178  0.15553849
  0.15553849  0.15739014  0.15924178  0.15924178  0.16109343  0.16109343
  0.16109343  0.15739014  0.15924178  0.16109343  0.15924178  0.16109343
  0.16109343  0.16109343  0.16109343  0.15924178  0.16109343  0.16109343
  0.16664838  0.17035168  0.17035168  0.17220333  0.14628024  0.14257695
  0.1444286   0.12591211  0.10369233  0.09813738  0.10184068  0.09813738
  0.09998903  0.09628573  0.09998903  0.09443408  0.09813738  0.09998903
  0.09258243  0.09813738  0.09998903  0.09998903  0.09813738  0.09628573
  0.08147254  0.08147254  0.07776924  0.07776924  0.05369781  0.04814287
  0.02962638  0.02962638  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

I don't see why it would work with `hist` but not `n_zero_rows`.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: Found out the `n_zero_rows` size changes in the loop for different images.

Answer (score 0):

We asked for an example, something we can actually run and test.  Without that we can only guess.  Here's a minimal example that produces this error.  There are other things that do it, but I suspect this is the most likely scenario:

```
In [770]: np.float32([[1,2],[3,4]])
Out[770]: 
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]], dtype=float32)
In [771]: np.float32([[1],[3,4]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-771-0b5ad69cbd8c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.float32([[1],[3,4]])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: I added more details. Sorry !